# How can I view a profiling session saved to the database using SqlServerStorage?

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I've configured [MiniProfiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) to use the SqlServerStorage. Does MiniProfiler have a built in way to view these saved profiling sessions in a similar way that you would view them at the time they were generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not built in way at the moment to browse the list of old profiling sessions.

However, we plan to build a sampling profiler at some point in the future and this would be included in the work.